Comparison of clocks running at different heights in a gravitational field
I hope this question has not yet been asked. If so then please link me to the answer.
If I build an apparatus which, on flicking a switch, sends a light beam, a distance to a mirror, and reflects it back to the start. And if this journey is timed by an onboard clock that displays the time on a digital display. Now if I have two identical devices, and run one on the earths surface while I run the other at an altitude. Each device measures (I assume) the interval between two events. Being the sending out of the beam and its return. Now an observer at each device will read the interval displayed on the device (yes it will be small but, since this is a thought experiment - bear with me). Now once we have done this once, we return the two devices to the earths surface and compare the recorded intervals. Assuming that, during the experiment, each clock measured the proper time between the events, would the two displays show the exact same numbers, being the two proper times for the two events? This despite the idea that the clock at altitude would tick "faster" than the clock on the earths surface.
We have heard how two identical clocks have been run, for extended time periods, at different altitudes, and then being reunited have been shown to have recorded different times. Just wondering how this would show up if we can read the passage of time, in either case, from a display. Once the clocks have been returned to the same altitude, being the frame of one of the clocks.

Am I understanding the experiment correctly: Each device sends a light beam to the other one, measuring the time interval between sending and receiving the reflection?

Sorry but no. Each device is totally separate, There is no communication between them. Each device, measures the time-of flight of the beam from source to mirror and back.

Oh. Each mirror is at a known distance (as measured in the reference frame of the respective device) from the respective origin of the beam then? I'm then missing the point of the question (the light speed is well known! ;-) ).

Beaming the light between the devices could be interesting because space may look differently for the two observers (in particular: shorter for one of them) so that in spite of the well-known speed of light different times are measured. I'm not perfectly sure that is the case but it's at least conceivable (I would expect the clocks to differ because of gravity, and the only explanation would be a difference in distance).

Dear Peter. This is what I am getting at. If GR did not predict a difference in the rate of time at the two altitudes then, we have only 3 parameters. Time, distance and light speed. These would obviously be identical in the two devices and  according to the two observers. No Problem. However, GR tells us the time passes faster in the weaker gravitational field. The question is how will this become apparent to the two observers? Will the numbers on the two devices show the exact same numbers (being a measure of elapsed proper time)? I believe YES since both devices will show proper time.

Then how is it that time will pass quicker higher up? Is it manifest in the fact that, if we could start the two devices simultaneously (and we all know the arguments against that) then the  process for the top device will conclude earlier than the bottom device ? I don't know. So yes, we have displayed proper time (which I am assuming will read the same for both devices) and we have the speed of light, which is the same for both devices. So we are only left with possibly a difference in the L of the two devices. Or am I wrong here ?

Here's a description of this experiment done in 2005.  The author, Tom van Baak, is a collector of atomic clocks. He left part of his collection at sea level in Seattle, and took part of his collection a kilometer up Mt. Rainier for a weekend, in a station wagon with his children. When he brought the mobile clocks back down and compared them with the stationary clocks, the mobile clocks were all ahead by a couple dozen nanoseconds. He calls the time difference "the best extra 22 nanoseconds I've ever spent with my kids."
Now suppose that, instead of spending one weekend on the mountaintop, the experiment had lasted for one billion weekends.  (We'll neglect inconveniences like "geological change.")  In that case, the time difference between the sea-level clocks and the high-altitude clocks would have increased by a factor of a billion, to twenty-two seconds. This is plenty large enough that a display showing times from both clocks would show the time difference, without any complications about the communication time.
Comparing remote clocks is a surprisingly tricky problem.  The most common approach at present is the Network Time Protocol, which typically allows computer clocks to synchronize over the internet with a precision of a few milliseconds or tens of milliseconds.  The satellites in the Global Positioning System famously require a correction for general relativity, so that they are communicating about time differences using the time as it elapses on the ground, rather than time as is elapses in orbit.

Thank you Rob for your very interesting and informative response.  I will still read the links that you have provided. Very much appreciated.

I am pretty sure the clocks were fast, from theory as well as the chart ;-). I also don't think he compared them with clocks that had stayed at low altitude; the way I read the graphs he measured the same clocks at home before and after the trip, seeing a discontinuity of around the predicted 22 ns (the x axis is labeled phase shift).

I love the idea of having a bit of extra time enjoying the mountain top. Must climb more mountains.

Is your answer to this question that the two observers would have measured a different time on their light clocks? That's how it reads.

@Peter Measured the same clocks relative to what? You can't tell whether a clock has gained or lost time unless you have another clock to compare it with; and if your two clocks disagree, you can't decide which one you trust unless you have a third clock which agrees with one, but not the other, of the first two. If you are a person who prefers statistical analyses, a good number of clocks is ten-ish. For most of history the "reference clock" was astronomical motion, but by the twentieth century we could build oscillators with better frequency stability than Earth's rotation.

@ProfRob Yes, the times on the two clocks will diverge. The two observers can discover this by coming back together, as in the linked experiment, and as you describe in v2 of your answer: they'll disagree about how long the experiment has lasted.  But the two observers can also measure the divergence by both staying in their high- and low-altitude locations, communicating over the gap using a synchronization protocol like the one I mentioned. The communication delay would remain constant as the readings on the two clocks diverge.

That is not the question though. The question is whether the observers would disagree on the time it takes for a light beam to bounce between the two mirrors. They don't. Just as the frequency of a laser does not change in space.

@ProfRob Oh, I see. I didn't realize that the question was about a single-shot experiment. I will spend some time thinking about whether to update or replace this answer; most of it is still applicable, but the reasons might be non-obvious.

@rob I realized that after I had written it: A clock is always true and continuous with reference to itself now, is it ;-). But I see that you corrected the "slow".

About the way I understand the setup that you are describing:
There is for instance Foucault's measurement of the speed of light
(Foucault inferred the transit time of the light from the angular velocity of the rotating mirror. The more precise Foucault could ascertain the angular velocity of the mirror, the higher the accuracy of the inferred transit time.)

The way I understand your question:
What if we can obtain the value of the transit time to a level of accuracy such that it is sensitive to the fact that for clocks at different elevation there is a difference in elapsed proper time.
We will assume that the transit distance is measured using geometric surveying methods, such as Foucault had to use. (Nowadays large distances are measured using laser ranging, but in this thought experiment that would defeat the purpose.)
The direct answer:
At every elevation the measured transit time would be the same.

Next:
discussion of why it comes out the same, even though deeper in a gravitational well the amount of proper time that elapses (for an observer) is smaller.
I will first discuss a simpler case: time and space on a rotating object.
Imagine a large wheel-shaped space station that is rotating. Levels that are closer to the axis of rotation are moving at a slower tangential velocity than levels that are further away from the axis of rotation.
So the levels further away from the axis of rotation are subject to a larger velocity time dilation effect than the levels closer to the axis of rotation.
Concurrent with the time dilation effect there is a spatial effect that is usually referred to with the name Ehrenfest paradox
When you are a geometric surveyor on that space station, and you measure out a distance, then further away from the axis of rotation the distance you measure out (in tangential direction) is relativistically contracted (relative to levels closer to the axis of rotation).
The time dilation effect and the spatial contraction effect correlate in such a way that at every distance to the axis of rotation a measurement of the speed of light finds the same value.

In terms of General Relativity we have that there is both a gravitational time dilation effect and gravitational spatial distortion.
(In fact, back when Einstein developed General Relativity the Ehrenfest paradox was among the clues that made Einstein suspect that a relativistic theory of gravity must exhibit spatial effect.)
The gravitational time dilation effect and the gravitational spatial distortion effect are correlated in such a way that at every elevation in the gravitational well a measurement of the speed of light finds the same value.

Dear Cleonis. Thank you. I do believe that this is exactly what I am getting at. Especially your last paragraph. Any text which discusses the Schwarzschild solution, discusses proper length (in a gravitational field) and coordinate length. There is a mathematical relation between the two. I believe the coordinate length to be the "gravitational distortion" you mention. Not  sure if this in correct? Now what confuses me it that the "coordinate distance" is said to have "no metrical significance". I am not quite sure what that means?

I  think it means that we cannot use coordinate distance to measure the separation of two points but must use the proper distance. Much like the "improper length" of an object in Special Relativity (in the direction of motion) is simply the viewpoint of an observer, for whom the object measured is moving relative to. Is that more or less correct ?

@PaulHinrichsen In your comments to my answer you are veering towards speculating on the basis of sparse information/knowledge. I recommend against that. To get a general idea of spacetime curvature I recommend the article by Andrew J. S. Hamilton and Jason P. Lisle: 'The river model of black holes'. (It's about spacetime curvature in general, not specifically about black holes.) The river model is not a new theory. Rather it offers a heuristic that facilitates thinking of velocity effect and gravitational effect in relation to each other.

Thank you Cleonis. I will take a look at that link.

If the mirrors are a fixed length apart and identical, then assuming that the apparatus is small enough that the spacetime can be considered locally flat, then the proper time interval measured by an observer with the apparatus will be $2L/c$. It does not matter where the apparatus is. That is the straightforward answer to the question you have asked.
The confusion is over what happens if you do this experiment by repeating it lots of times for two sets of instruments at different heights and then bring them back together - this is essentially what is done by flying atomic clocks on aeroplanes etc. There, the two observers will disagree on how many times the light bounced back and forth even though they agree on the amount of time it should have taken for one bounce to occur. (If we are talking atomic clocks, both observers agree that they work on some particular frequency and it doesn't change if they take the clock somewhere else).
How is this reconciled? The observers would disagree over how long the experiment had lasted in total. The light clock of the observer higher up would apparently have run faster and completed more bounces than the one lower down.

Thank you. That's an interesting take on the issue. If I understand you correctly, both ground-based observer and the observer at altitude, agree on the time for one bounce of the light and yet might disagree on the number of times the light did bounce. Yet what if the apparatus could increment a counter each time the beam bounced ? At the end of it all the counter would display a number and surely both must agree on the value of that number ?

@PaulHinrichsen no. They would disagree on how long the experiment has lasted and would disagree on how many times the light has bounced back and forth.

@PaulHinrichsen Locally, light speed is always c (which is what each clock measures, locally). But the outside observer sees a slower speed in the gravitational well (approaching zero at the Schwarzschild radius). The atomic clock also runs on EM ! .... In a sense, gravitational lensing is like normal lensing by a material. In both cases, the light speed is slower in the "lens": In both cases the light "takes" the fastest route (not because it is smart but because this is how the waves propagating everywhere all at once do and don't cancel each other out under the given conditions).
